# At what point is HD content downgraded to SD from a service provider?

Tags: video-quality, cable

Is the High Definition (HD) content provided by cable companies through fiber and copper downgraded, to Standard Definition (SD) at the cable box?

Comment: My cable provider uses separate 'channels' for SD and HD content. No idea whether they get them that way from their providers, but for sure they're not downrezing in the STB.

Comment: I would assume that video would be very similar to images. You can't upscale without quality loss. Satellite (HD) => Receiver (HD) => Line - Fiber (HD) => House - Copper (HD) => Box (HD) / Downgraded to SD => TV